# Angular.js: change a class with ng-class and a click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I have this array of objects on my controller (self.years)

```
    var self = this;

    self.years =[
        {"year":"2010"},
        {"year":"2011"},
        {"year":"2012"},
        {"year":"2013"},
        {"year":"2014"},
        {"year":"2015"}
    ];
```

In my markup I'm using that to make a button for each object using ng-repeat:

```
         <div class="btn-container col-md-2" ng-repeat="year in ctrl.years">
            <button class='btn year-btn' year="{{$index}}" ng-click="ctrl.updateYear($index)">{{year.year}}</button>
         </div>
```

If on my controller I have a yearSelected already plus a click function for each button to change that yearSelected:

```
self.yearSelected = self.years[5];

self.updateYear = function(indexSelected) {
    self.yearSelected = self.years[indexSelected];
};
```

...how do I give that corresponding button to yearSelected a "selected" class using ng-class?

Comment: You could do `ng-class="{selected: self.yearSelected === year.year }"`

Comment: Pankaj's answer works as well assuming you don't have repeating values in you array at any point. Otherwise, you would get multiple highlighted buttons. If you have repeating years ever, you'd need to track by $index which you should probably do anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.updateYear = function(indexSelected) {
    self.currentIndex = indexSelected; // add this
    self.yearSelected = self.years[indexSelected];
};
```

On the UI, add ng-class="{ 'active': $index === currentIndex }" to your button

Answer (score 0):

```
self.yearSelected = self.years[0];

self.updateYear = function(year) {
    self.yearSelected = year;
};


<div class="btn-container col-md-2" ng-repeat="obj in ctrl.years">
    <button class='btn year-btn' ng-click="ctrl.updateYear(obj)">{{obj.year}}</button>
</div>

//use ng-class="{active: self.yearSelected === obj.year }"
```